# Using Admin Panel How we can create a aspx page in sitefinity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitefinity

how we can create the dynamic page ex. help.aspx and write the code in sitefinity. Because i facing a problem I create a page but i unable to know in which directory the page is lived. If any one help me Suggest.

http://abc.com/sitefinity/admin/pages.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure I understand your question correctly. When you create a page in Sitefinity, it doesn't create an ASPX file. The data for the page is kept in the database and served from there. There are no physical files involved.

If you want to write some code that executes when a page loads, you have two options:

1. Put the code into a control and drop the control on a page created from within Sitefinity
2. Create a regular ASPX page from Visual Studio and include it as an **external page** in Sitefinity.

I would recommend the first option, as this would provide you with all the Sitefinity goodness that all pages use - templates, editing through the browser, etc.

If you wanted something else and I misunderstood, please be more specific.

Slavo, The Sitefinity Team